# How to avoid sql error, when deleting an event?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-api

When I try to delete an event with the SonarQube REST API I get an error:

> {"err_code":500,"err_msg":"ActiveRecord::JDBCError: Unknown column 'scope' in 'where clause': SELECT * FROM `snapshots` WHERE (uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND scope = 'PRJ')  LIMIT 1"}

I use SonarQube 6.2

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: Did you have a look at the database table itself? What is the callstack and/or errorlog?